# Can I count number of SUBSEQUENT rows with values larger than current row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, count

```
Row Input Output    Output Explanation
1   14.93   6       6 because input value on rows 2 to 7 are smaller than row 1
2   9.74    0       0 because input value on row 3 is larger than row 2
3   12.89   0       0 because input value on row 4 is larger than row 3
4   13.09   2       2 because input value on rows 5 to 6 are smaller than row 4
5   7.84    0       0 because input value on row 6 is larger than row 5
6   12.81   0       0 because input value on row 7 is larger than row 6
7   13.15   0       0 because input value on row 8 is larger than row 7
8   18.15   0       0 because input value in row 8 is last in series
```

Please can you help me with defining the SQL server code for the logic in the table?

I have tried a number of different approaches including recursive CTEs, CAST, LEAD… OVER..., etc. My SQL skills are not up to this challenge, which seems to be easy to describe in words, but difficult to code!

Please not the logic in the last row is different from the rest.

MAX output value should be 244.

Comment: Hi FunnyMoney, welcome to SO.  Could you post any code that you've tried, so far, and give us a clear example of what you'd expect from the output, please?  Also, I'd recommend reading the [help], and taking the [tour].

Comment: Thank you for reformatting the table Paul. I am a new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @FunnyMoney are there gaps in the column Row?

Comment: In reality the ROW will be a string ID, so creating the row number from the string ID is important as per Popeye's reply below: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROW) AS RN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @t table
(
Row int,
Input decimal(5,2)
);

insert into @t(Row, Input)
values
(1,   14.93),
(2,   9.74),   
(3,   12.89),  
(4,   13.09), 
(5,   7.84),   
(6,   12.81),  
(7,   13.15),  
(8,   18.15);

select *, 
    case 
        when lead(a.Input) over(order by a.Row) < a.Input then 
        (
            select count(*) - count(xyz) 
            from 
            (
                select case when b.Input < a.Input then null else b.Input end as xyz
                from @t as b 
                where b.Row > a.Row
            ) as c
        ) 
        else 0 
    end as Output
from @t as a;
```

Comment: Thanks IPTR this does seem to work! However, I will need to open another question as I would also like to group by a third column with a category and I failed to specify this in my original request. I don't want to confuse the community here, so I will start again with another post and refer back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can easily be done with window functions. We need to iterate for each original row, while keeping track of the original value.

I would use a recursive query here:

```
with
    data as (select t.*, row_number() over(order by row) rn from mytable t),
    cte as (
        select row, rn, input, 0 as output from data
        union all
        select c.row, d.rn, c.input, c.output + 1
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.rn = c.rn + 1 and d.input < c.input
    )
select input, max(output) as output 
from cte 
group by row, input 
order by row
```

For each row, the logic is to iteratively check the following rows. It the following value is smaller than the one on the original row, we increment the `output` counter; if it is not, the recursion stops for that row. Then all that is left to do is keep the greatest counter per original row.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7fa70e684b099d8df2265dd080bfcbd7)**:

```
input | output
----: | -----:
14.93 |      6
 9.74 |      0
12.89 |      0
13.09 |      2
 7.84 |      0
12.81 |      0
13.15 |      0
18.15 |      0
```

Comment: Thanks GMB. I get 0s for all the values. Plus there is a recursive loop max of 100. I would like the count to go to a maximum of 244 please. (I have edited my original question to add this detail).

Comment: @FunnyMoney: the query was missing a few things... I fixed it, and added a fiddle to my answer.

Comment: Thanks GMB this does seem to work! However, I will need to open another question as I would also like to group by a third column with a category and I failed to specify this in my original request. I don't want to confuse the community here, so I will start again with another post and refer back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT T.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROW) AS RN 
   FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
SELECT C.ROW, C.INPUT, 
       COALESCE((SELECT MIN(CC.RN) - C.RN - 1 
                   FROM CTE CC
                  WHERE CC.INPUT > C.INPUT AND CC.RN > C.RN) 
                , 0) AS OUTPUT
FROM CTE C;
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising, however, I get the following:
The multi-part identifier "T.ROW" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "T.INPUT" could not be bound.
Can the max output also be limited to 244 please?

Comment: It was due to missing alias. Please check the updated answer now!!

Comment: I think we are getting close. I now get:
Column 'CTE.RN' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Please can we also have a maximum of 244 as the output? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Popeye. The output does not seem right. Lots of negative numbers.
input | output
----: | -----:
14.93 |      6
 9.74 |      -2
12.89 |      -3
13.09 |      -4
 7.84 |      -5
12.81 |      -6
13.15 |      -7
18.15 |      0

Comment: Ohfo!! This made me crazy. I wanted to give simple solution. Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `apply`:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by row) as seqnum,
             1 + count(*) over () as cnt
      from mytable t
     )
select t.*, coalesce(coalesce(t2.min_seqnum, t.cnt) - t.seqnum - 1, 0) as output
from t outer apply
     (select min(t2.seqnum) as min_seqnum
      from t t2
      where t2.row > t.row and t2.input > t.input
     ) t2
order by row;
```

The idea is to find the next row that is *bigger* than the current row.  The slight complication (why `cnt` is needed) is in case there is no larger row.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf5537b6c52cd38e0a5e0f06d91927d4) is a db<>fiddle.